# Grep to extract a word that starts and ends with a certain pattern

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a log file with entries like

```
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abc:12 insertTotal=11  ERROR: [doc=abc:d1c3f0]
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abcd:12 insertTotal=11 ERROR: [doc=def:d1cwqw3f0]
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=def:134 insertTotal=11  
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abkfe insertTotal=11
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=lmkfe insertTotal=11
INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=lmkfe insertTotal=11
```

I need to grep the part between **[doc=** and **]** i.e abc:d1c3f0 and def:d1cwqw3f0
So I am looking to do something like 
^(abc|def)*]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` to the rescue:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=\[doc=)[^\]]+' file
abc:d1c3f0
def:d1cwqw3f0
```

It gets everything from `doc=` (`(?<=\[doc=)` part) up to anything before the `]` char (`[^\]]+` part).

Or with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"[][=]" '{print $5}' file
abc:d1c3f0
def:d1cwqw3f0
```

`-F"[][=]"` defines different possible field separators `[`, `]` or `=`. Then, it prints the 5th "piece".

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui. Could you please explain the answer too.

Answer (score 4):

or `sed`:

`sed -n 's/.*\[doc=\(.*\)\].*/\1/p' filename`

`-n`: don't print lines

`.*\[doc=` match anything that ends with `[doc=`

`\(.*\)` store as many characters as you can in a buffer while still finishing the match

`\].*` match a `]` followed by as much as possible

`\1` replace all that was matched with the contents of the `\(.*\)`

`p` print this line